# Selenium grid file upload error org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am using selenium grid for file upload, file upload is working for 1kb file but if I am trying to upload a 11mb file it throws the below

> org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: 'ip-x-x-x-xx.ec2.internal', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.209-160.335.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:122)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:140)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:69)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
> at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:87)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.upload(RemoteWebElement.java:116)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:102)
> at pageobjectrep.CampaignPge.uploadSampleMultipleMediaFile(CampaignPge.java:565)
> at stepDefinations.Campaigns.uploadSampleMultipleMediaFile(Campaigns.java:248)
> at ✽.Upload Sample Multiple Media File "11mb.pdf"(classpath:features/CSP/MMSCampaign.feature:37)

Code to upload-

```html
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
        if (fileName.isEmpty())
        {
            fileName = "mmm.txt";
        }
        File file;
        file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("MAC")) {
            element.sendKeys(file + FileReader.getInstance().getConfigReader().getmmsfilePath() + fileName);
        }else{
            LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
            File file1 = detector.getLocalFile(file+FileReader.getInstance().getConfigReader().getmmsfilePath()+fileName);
            ((RemoteWebElement) element).setFileDetector(detector);
            element.sendKeys(file1.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

Comment: Is there any error reported on node or hub? Looks like your client code tries to deserialize response from hub but it is not proper json.

Comment: I dont see any error in hub or node.